# how to determine field offset in stat struct calling from assembly?

Tags: assembly, struct, offset, abi, stat

In order to get `struct stat` describing file one would call *stat family of functions that will fill memory that is pointed to by passed  pointer with struct values.

In *C* we can call *POSIX.1-2008* offsetof macro, but it is a macro, not available in assembly.

How to determine size of struct from assembly and how to determine offsets of fields, so that one could extract necessary fields like `st_size`, `st_mode` and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ABI for the platform determines the rules for C struct padding.  For example, x86-64 Linux uses [the x86-64 System V ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI).

Hard way: read the ABI and work it out yourself.  Links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.  (It's not actually that hard, the rules for alignment / padding within structs are quite simple for the x86-64 System V ABI: every member goes in order of declaration, and is naturally aligned.  This can require padding.  Windows x64 has its own struct-layout rules that don't always produce the same layout.)

Easy way: let the compiler calculate the offsets for you by writing a function that stores into the struct, and look at the asm.  e.g.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
void foo(struct stat *st) {
    st->st_size = 1;
    st->st_mode = 2;  // different numbers so you know which field is which in the output
}

    mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+48], 1
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+24], 2
    ret
```

(from the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:%27-xc+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3%27,source:%27%23include+%3Csys/stat.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+foo(struct+stat+*st)+%7B%0A++++st-%3Est_size+%3D+1%3B%0A++++st-%3Est_mode+%3D+2%3B%0A%7D%27)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3))

---

#### Having the compiler output constants for use in separate .asm / .S

See some other Q&As with answers geared towards automating the process of generating definitions like `#define` or `.equ`, or NASM `equ`:

- [How to access a C struct member in ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77814957/how-to-access-a-c-struct-member-in-asm)
- [How can I print the offset of a struct member at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208830/how-can-i-print-the-offset-of-a-struct-member-at-compile-time/69209993#69209993)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on "let the compiler calculate..." and where to find ABI for amd64 platform?

Comment: @BulatM. There are two ABIs for amd64. One used by Windows and the other one (the amd64 SysV ABI) is used by most other operating systems. Which one do you want?

Comment: @BulatM.: ABI links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: Very useful, found.

Comment: @Peter, I recall that it is possible to give options to compiler so that it will 'pack' the structture, without using padding for proper alignment. Could it broke code that conforms to ABI, and how to determine that structure is 'packed'?

Comment: @BulatM.: I don't remember a compiler option for it, because that would change the ABI.  glibc and the Linux kernel are not compiled with that option, so if such an option existed, you couldn't use it if you wanted to make system / library calls.   You can use `__attribute__((packed))` on a specific struct, and that would change its layout if the original version did have any padding.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a case where it’s easier to write a C module with a *templated* inline assembler section which uses references to `struct` members in its input and output arguments.

```c
struct my_struct {
    int *a;
    int b;
};

int my_function(struct my_struct *p, int other) {
    int result;
    __asm__(
        "add %[pa], %[pb]\n"
        "add %[pb], %[other]\n"
        "some_command %[result], %[pb]"
        : [result] "=rm"(result), [pa] "+rm"(*p->a), [pb] "+r"(p->b)
        : [other] "g"(other)
        : "cc");
    return result;
}
```

(This inline assembler template syntax is a [C extension supported by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) and maybe Clang.)

Comment: Your template doesn't reference `%[result]` so there's no way it can work to let the compiler pick whatever register it wants for output with `"=r"`.  Maybe a better template example would be `"add %[result], %[a1], %[mode_offset]"` to generate a pointer, exactly like `result = &(struct stat*)arg1->st_mode;`  But yes, *if* you can cram your asm into a GNU C Extended asm statement (in a non-`naked` function), then this is a good shortcut.  Otherwise you could use inline asm to emit `.equ` definitions for use in separate asm, like the links to other Q&As I added to my answer.

Comment: Usually if you're using inline asm in C, you could just set the struct members from pure C code.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Of course! I hadn’t even thought about what OP (likely) wants to achieve with `struct` offsets. I reworked my answer according to your idea.