# sizeof(enum) not behaving as expected

Tags: c, gcc, enums, arm, 32bit-64bit

I am compiling following code using gcc for 32-bit arm mcu.

```
    static int test_sanity_enum_size(void)
{
    enum smallchoices { sa, sb, sc };
    enum medchoices { ma, mb, mc, md, me, mf, mg, mh, mi, mj, mk, ml };
    enum largechoices {
        a01, b01, c01, d01, e01, f01, g01, h01, i01, j01,
        a02, b02, c02, d02, e02, f02, g02, h02, i02, j02,
        a03, b03, c03, d03, e03, f03, g03, h03, i03, j03,
        a04, b04, c04, d04, e04, f04, g04, h04, i04, j04,
        a05, b05, c05, d05, e05, f05, g05, h05, i05, j05,
        a06, b06, c06, d06, e06, f06, g06, h06, i06, j06,
        a07, b07, c07, d07, e07, f07, g07, h07, i07, j07,
        a08, b08, c08, d08, e08, f08, g08, h08, i08, j08,
        a09, b09, c09, d09, e09, f09, g09, h09, i09, j09,
        a10, b10, c10, d10, e10, f10, g10, h10, i10, j10,
        xxx };

    /* Enum size */
    if (!TEST_size_t_eq(sizeof(enum smallchoices), sizeof(int))
        || !TEST_size_t_eq(sizeof(enum medchoices), sizeof(int))
        || !TEST_size_t_eq(sizeof(enum largechoices), sizeof(int)))
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

The functions returns 0. While all the 3 enums have only few elements so by default the enum types will be int types so I am expecting the function to return 1 but it returns 0. Do I need to modify the test condition or the enum arrays so that the function returns 1?

Comment: Why don't you just print out the `sizeof` value to find out for yourself what it is? You'll probably find it is smaller than an `int`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the size of an enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c)

Comment: If you cannot print on the target processor, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69209993/298225) has information on extracting values of compile-time expressions from GCC. For example, replace the `offsetof(struct A, b)` in it with `sizeof(enum smallchoices)`.

Answer (score 3):

You write ...

> While all the 3 enums have only few elements so by default the enum types will be int types

... but although `enum` types are *integer* types, it is not safe to conclude that they are compatible specifically with `int`.  On the contrary, the language specification says this:

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer
> type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
> implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the
> values of all the members of the enumeration.

(C17 6.7.2.2/4)

None of your `enum`s has too many constants or constants with too large a value for them to be made compatible with `char`, so the full range of types is available for the implementation to choose.

> Do I need to modify the test condition or the enum arrays so that the
> function returns 1?

There are no arrays there, but I suppose you mean the enumerator lists in the enum definitions.  There is no way to *ensure* that your `enum` types will be compatible with `int` in every C implementation, but you have a fairly good chance of getting `int`-size enums by specifying a range of enumerator values that require at least that large a representation.  For example,

```
    enum smallchoices { sa, sb, sc = INT_MAX };
    enum medchoices { ma, mb, mc, md, me, mf, mg, mh, mi, mj, mk, ml = INT_MAX };
    enum largechoices {
        a01, b01, c01, d01, e01, f01, g01, h01, i01, j01,
        a02, b02, c02, d02, e02, f02, g02, h02, i02, j02,
        a03, b03, c03, d03, e03, f03, g03, h03, i03, j03,
        a04, b04, c04, d04, e04, f04, g04, h04, i04, j04,
        a05, b05, c05, d05, e05, f05, g05, h05, i05, j05,
        a06, b06, c06, d06, e06, f06, g06, h06, i06, j06,
        a07, b07, c07, d07, e07, f07, g07, h07, i07, j07,
        a08, b08, c08, d08, e08, f08, g08, h08, i08, j08,
        a09, b09, c09, d09, e09, f09, g09, h09, i09, j09,
        a10, b10, c10, d10, e10, f10, g10, h10, i10, j10,
        xxx = INT_MAX };
```

In principle, an implementation could use some kind of compressed representation with that, but I am not aware of any implementation going to such lengths to save space.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are problematic because an enumerated type, the variable itself, can have implementation-defined size as long as it is large enough to hold all specified items. Something like `enum smallchoices { sa, sb, sc };` can fit inside a 8 bit integer type, so it's rather common that embedded systems compilers in particular optimize it down to 8 bits. So your "sanity test" is wrong, it's in conflict with the C standard.

On the other hand, enumerated constants, these: `sa, sb, sc`, are guaranteed to always be of type `int`.

Thus if you need portable code with fixed size enums (or just 32 bit aligned chunks), then you shouldn't use `enum` for the actual storage, but one of the `intn_t` types from `stdint.h` (likely `uint32_t` in this case). You can still use `typedef enum` etc to create a list of constants, but just don't use that type for storage if deterministic size matters.