# How to access a C struct member in ASM

Tags: c, assembly, struct, stm32

I am using a mixture of C and ASM code to program an STM32H745 in STCubeIDE.

I have the following struct to ensure strict ordering of variables that are shared among the two cores CM4 and CM7:

```
struct miscSharedMemoryStruct {
   volatile uint32_t triggerPtr;
   volatile uint32_t bufferHead;
}
__attribute__((section(".sram3"))) struct miscSharedMemoryStruct miscSharedMemory;
```

The section `.sram3` is defined in the linker script and accessing my variables in C code for both cores works well. So far, so good. However...

To enable the access of entries of `miscSharedMemory`, I set the variable as global in my ASM code:

```
.global miscSharedMemory
```

To be able for the assembler to recognize the right address, I added the following define statement to the header, in which the above struct is defined:

```
#define BUFFER_HEAD_ADR  ((uintptr_t)(&miscSharedMemory.bufferHead))
```

In the end, the idea is to get data from the adress above into a register in my ASM code:

```
ldr R1, =BUFFER_HEAD_ADR
```

However, when compiling my code, I get a

> undefined reference to 'BUFFER_HEAD_ADR'

**What is the correct way to make the assembler recognize the right address to my variable in the struct?** I probably don't need to do the `.global` statement, as long as the address stored in `BUFFER_HEAD_ADR` is correct and recognized by the assembler, but I just don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: `#define` is a preprocessor construct, it will not be in the symbol table so the assembler can't see it. Just do `ldr r1, =miscSharedMemory+4`

Comment: I don't want to hardcode it. That's what I did before and it's not the most elegant solution in my opinion.

Comment: Then instead of a define create an actual variable in memory. Will incur the penalty of another memory access. `uint32_t *BUFFER_HEAD_ADR = &miscSharedMemory.bufferHead;` then `ldr r1, =BUFFER_HEAD_ADR; ldr r1, [r1]`

Comment: Is there no way to get the offset automatically calculated, initiated by the ASM code?

Comment: As part of your build script, you could have a C program that `#include`s the headers with your struct definitions and uses `offsetof(type, member)` to printf the offsets and total sizes (at least of members that your asm uses) in a format like `.equ type_member, 12` assemble-time constant definitions that your asm files can `#include` or `.include`.

Comment: @PeterCordes This is almost exactly what I do, and it's been one of the best design choices I have ever made for readable assembly. From reading about UNIX history, I know Ken Thompson could use C to comfortably rewrite UNIX only after structs were added and original structs were basically equivalent to global (they're scoped to their struct typein newer Cs) offset defines (with type casts and minor syntactic sugar). It can make a huge difference in readability and maintainability (if ensure your build system correctly keeps the defines in sync with the actual struct layout).

Comment: @PeterCordes, that'll take me a while to digest. What has worked for me is using a `#define` statement that the assembler recognizes, hardcoding `#define BUFFER_HEAD_ADR 0x3040000UL`. I just wished I could replace this hardcoded address with some sort of preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Address Calculation Solution for Assembly in STM32H745**

In tackling the challenge of dynamically calculating addresses in assembly code for an STM32H745 microcontroller, I've crafted a solution that prioritizes flexibility and transparency without resorting to script extraction or hardcoded values.

**1. Initial Problem:**
The objective was to load data from a specific address in assembly without hardcoding it, considering the evolving nature of the code and the necessity for predictability when accessing shared memory across different cores.

**2. Use of `struct` for Ordering:**
To maintain strict ordering of variables shared among cores, a `struct` named `miscSharedMemoryStruct` was introduced. This `struct`, residing in the `.sram3` section, contains variables like `triggerPtr` and `bufferHead`.

**3. Dynamic Address Storage:**
The challenge lay in dynamically calculating the address of `miscSharedMemory.bufferHead` during compile time, as the actual address is unknown until the linker defines it.

**4. Register-Relative Load Solution:**
The core idea involves:

1. The use of a register-relative load instead of a PC-relative load as used in my initial post
2. The storage of the address in the `.data` section of the assembly code.

**5. C Code:**

```
struct miscSharedMemoryStruct {
   volatile uint32_t triggerPtr;
   volatile uint32_t bufferHead;
} __attribute__((section(".sram3"))) struct miscSharedMemoryStruct miscSharedMemory;

extern volatile uint32_t *bufferHeadAdr;
bufferHeadAdr = (uint32_t *) &miscSharedMemory.bufferHead;
```

**6. ASM Code:**

```
.global bufferHeadAdr


.data

CBAdr:
variableA:     .word 0
variableB:     .word 0
.
.
bufferHeadAdr: .word 0
.
.


.text

LDR R0, =CBAdr
LDR R1, [R0, #bufferHeadAdr - CBAdr]
```

In the assembly code, `bufferHeadAdr` is declared global, and its address is stored in the `.data` section. The actual address is then loaded into register `R1` using register-relative addressing.

Note that the utilization of `LDR R0, =CBAdr` incurs no runtime impact in my specific case. I declare `R0` anyways and keep it unchanged throughout my code, facilitating extensive access to other data in my `.data` section.

Comment: If you care about memory ordering between cores, you should normally be using `_Atomic uint32_t` with at least `acquire` / `release`.   Just `volatile` has no ordering guarantees, like `memory_order_relaxed`.  (At least GCC / Clang do effectively define the behaviour of concurrent read+write on a volatile, and make sure to use full-width loads / stores to avoid tearing.)

Comment: Also, if grouping them into a struct was supposed to be relevant for ordering, you'd want `_Atomic struct miscSharedMemoryStruct  miscSharedMemory;` to make the whole 64-bit struct one atomic pair.  (But that can be costly for single-member access if the CPU doesn't provide cheap 64-bit pure-load and pure-store; compilers won't optimize `foo.member` into a load of just the member.)

Answer (score 5):

The assembler doesn't know how to parse C source and apply ABI rules for struct layout do derive the member offsets.  And text substitution with CPP macros like `#define` would put `((uintptr_t)(&miscSharedMemory.bufferHead))` into your asm source as if you'd typed that in the source.  So that's not helpful.

As part of your build script, you could have a C program that `#include`s the headers with your struct definitions and uses `offsetof(type, member)` to **`printf` the offsets** (at least of members that your asm uses) and maybe `sizeof(struct)` total sizes **in a format like `.equ type_member, 12`** assemble-time constant definitions that your asm files can `#include` or `.include`.

If you're using make, for example, you'd have a rule to build a `struct_offsets.inc` file, with dependencies on all the relevant `.h` files.  The rule would be to compile and run that C program with its output redirected to the target `.inc` file.  Object files (`.o`) built from asm sources that use that `.inc` get a dependency on it as well as the corresponding `.S`.

```c
// #include "foo.h"
// #include "bar.h"

struct foo {   // for example
  int a;
  int b;
};

#include <stddef.h>  // for offsetof
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

// C equivalent of C++ sizeof(type::member)
#define member_size(type, member) sizeof(((type *)0)->member)

static const char *offset_fmt = ".equ %s_%s, %d\n";
#define PRINT_OFFSET(T, member) printf(offset_fmt, #T, #member, offsetof(struct T, member))
// stringify the names, passed without the struct keyword.

int main(){
  PRINT_OFFSET(foo, a);
  PRINT_OFFSET(foo, b);

// optional: you'll notice a missing definition from asm error messages and add it to this helper program
// also, this isn't attempting to detect new members in the middle, just a fun idea in case you want something like this
  static_assert( (sizeof(struct foo) == (offsetof(struct foo, b) + member_size(struct foo, b))),
                         "there's a member we didn't print, or padding");
}
```

Compiles and runs as a C or C++ program ([on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:92,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:92,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:92,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:92,startLineNumber:17),source:%27//+%23include+%22foo.h%22%0A//+%23include+%22bar.h%22%0A%0Astruct+foo+%7B+++//+for+example%0A++int+a%3B%0A++int+b%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%23include+%3Cstddef.h%3E++//+for+offsetof%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cassert.h%3E%0A%0A//+C+equivalent+of+C%2B%2B+sizeof(type::member)%0A%23define+member_size(type,+member)+sizeof(((type+*)0)-%3Emember)%0A%0Astatic+const+char+*offset_fmt+%3D+%22.equ+%25s_%25s,+%25d%5Cn%22%3B%0A%23define+PRINT_OFFSET(T,+member)+printf(offset_fmt,+%23T,+%23member,+offsetof(struct+T,+member))%0A//+stringify+the+names,+passed+without+the+struct+keyword.%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++PRINT_OFFSET(foo,+a)%3B%0A++PRINT_OFFSET(foo,+b)%3B%0A%0A//+optional:+you!%27ll+notice+a+missing+definition+from+asm+error+messages+and+add+it+to+this+helper+program%0A//+also,+this+isn!%27t+attempting+to+detect+new+members+in+the+middle,+just+a+fun+idea+in+case+you+want+something+like+this%0A++static_assert(+(sizeof(struct+foo)+%3D%3D+(offsetof(struct+foo,+b)+%2B+member_size(struct+foo,+b))),%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++%22there!%27s+a+member+we+didn!%27t+print,+or+padding%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%232%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:46.58111093067277,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-Wall+-xc%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:60.79136690647482,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:60.79136690647482,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x64+msvc+v19.38%27,editorid:2,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:39.20863309352518,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:53.41888906932722,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) for an x86-64 target=host).  The output is:

```
.equ foo_a, 0
.equ foo_b, 4
```

This allows `ldr R1, =var + foo_b` or whatever.  Or in your case,

```
ldr R1, =miscSharedMemory + miscSharedMemoryStruct_bufferHead
```

You could use different naming conventions for the constants if you want, or even different conventions for different sets of structs if you use different macros or different format strings.

---

#### Cross compiling: this program needs to be built for the target ABI!

###### update: Workaround: [How can I print the offset of a struct member at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208830/how-can-i-print-the-offset-of-a-struct-member-at-compile-time/69209993#69209993)

You can use GNU C inline asm to format text which doesn't even have to be valid asm syntax, or can be an asm comment that has the infor you want.  (Use GCC, or `clang -no-integrated-as`, to not check asm statements for being "valid" asm for the target).  Or as Jester points out, you can emit `asm` statements with `.equ` directives.  With the right operands to the asm statement, you can emit a line of text with just plain numbers where you want them.

---

If cross-compiling, you want struct layouts for the target system, not e.g. an x86-64 host.  Hopefully you have an emulator or something that lets you run a program for the target system and collect its stdout.

If not `stdout`, then maybe assigning values in sequence to a `volatile size_t sink` global variable?  (And match that up with a list of what order you dump in.)

If not, maybe define global variables like `int foo_a = 0;` and so on, and extract the values from the `.o` instead of writing a program that prints them.  (`0` values will go in `.bss`, non-zero in `.data`, which isn't ideal.  Perhaps add a constant `0x1000` to all sizes so they all go in `.data`?)

If there was a way to give asm symbol names to each member of a struct global variable, you could just define one of each struct and process the output of `nm` on the object file to get the offsets from the symbol addresses (rather than having to dig into the data).

For a program that assigns in a known order to a `volatile int sink`, maybe parse the compiler asm output to see what values its loading into registers?  Perhaps even `gcc -fverbose-asm` to annotate instructions.  A debug build will compile each C statement separately, in program order, and not reuse any constants across statements.

```
struct foo {   // for example
  int a;
  char c[65532];
  int b;
};

#include <stddef.h>  // for offsetof
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <assert.h>

int main(){
    volatile size_t sink;  // local var to reduce noise of setting up addresses
#define PRINT_OFFSET(T, member) sink = offsetof(struct T, member)

  PRINT_OFFSET(foo, a);
  PRINT_OFFSET(foo, b);
  PRINT_OFFSET(foo, c);

  (void)sink;  // silence unused warning
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:24,endLineNumber:24,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:24,selectionStartColumn:24,selectionStartLineNumber:24,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:24),source:%27//+%23include+%22foo.h%22%0A//+%23include+%22bar.h%22%0A%0Astruct+foo+%7B+++//+for+example%0A++int+a%3B%0A++char+c%5B65532%5D%3B%0A++int+b%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%23include+%3Cstddef.h%3E++//+for+offsetof%0A//%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cassert.h%3E%0A%0A//+C+equivalent+of+C%2B%2B+sizeof(type::member)%0A%23define+member_size(type,+member)+sizeof(((type+*)0)-%3Emember)%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++volatile+size_t+sink%3B++//+local+var+to+reduce+noise+of+setting+up+addresses%0A//static+const+char+*offset_fmt+%3D+%22.equ+%25s_%25s,+%25d%5Cn%22%3B%0A%23define+PRINT_OFFSET(T,+member)+sink+%3D+offsetof(struct+T,+member)%0A%0A++PRINT_OFFSET(foo,+a)%3B%0A++PRINT_OFFSET(foo,+b)%3B%0A++PRINT_OFFSET(foo,+c)%3B%0A%0A++(void)sink%3B++//+silence+unused+warning%0A//+optional:+you!%27ll+notice+a+missing+definition+from+asm+error+messages+and+add+it+to+this+helper+program%0A//+also,+this+isn!%27t+attempting+to+detect+new+members+in+the+middle,+just+a+fun+idea+in+case+you+want+something+like+this%0A++static_assert(+(sizeof(struct+foo)+%3D%3D+(offsetof(struct+foo,+b)+%2B+member_size(struct+foo,+b))),%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++%22there!%27s+a+member+we+didn!%27t+print,+or+padding%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%232%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:46.91144708423326,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg1320,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O0+-Wall+-xc+-mcpu%3Dcortex-m3%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:19,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:19,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+ARM+GCC+13.2.0+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.326886575728054,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg1320,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O0+-Wall+-xc+-fverbose-asm%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+ARM+GCC+13.2.0+(Editor+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:53.08855291576674,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) - GCC `-O0 -Wall -xc -mcpu=cortex-m3`

```
main:
        push    {r7}
        sub     sp, sp, #12
        add     r7, sp, #0
        movs    r3, #0           # offsetof(struct foo, a)
        str     r3, [r7, #4]
        mov     r3, #65536       # offsetof(struct foo, b)
        str     r3, [r7, #4]
        movs    r3, #4           # offsetof(struct foo, c)
        str     r3, [r7, #4]
        ldr     r3, [r7, #4]     # (void)sink reload marks that we're done
        movs    r3, #0           # return value
        mov     r0, r3
        adds    r7, r7, #12
        mov     sp, r7
        ldr     r7, [sp], #4
        bx      lr
```

The first three `movs` / `movw` instructions are the three `offsetof` values we assign.  This is filtered asm from the Godbolt compiler explorer, but the raw output from `arm-none-...-gcc -S` won't have more instructions, just directives.  Lines that match the regex  `*mov.*#` are the ones you want.

New-enough Thumb mode (with `movw`) allows wide immediates, like 16 bit.  If `offsetof(foo, b)` has been one higher, it would `ldr` a 32-bit constant from a nearby literal pool, but I was pleasantly surprised to find GCC using simple `movs` / `movw` instructions for values up to 65536, so even large structs work simply.

Since we lose the names in the asm output (even with `gcc -fverbose-asm` unless you had a named global var for each value to assign), generate this `.c` programmatically from the same list of `type : member` that you're going to use to parse the output.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up. I am no expert in adapting the make file in STCubeIDE that would execute to create that `.inc` file before compiling the rest, so it'll take me a while to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @Hansel: Also note the edit: I realized after posting that we need to compile for the target system, not the host, so we might not be able to run the program on the build host.

Comment: Or use inline asm to generate the `.equ` directives complete with name.

Comment: Re “Cross compiling: this program needs to be built for the target ABI!”: Having to print on the target, and even having a target system available at all during build time, can be avoided by [using GCC’s extended assembly features and taking the value from the generated “assembly” code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208830/how-can-i-print-the-offset-of-a-struct-member-at-compile-time/69209993#69209993).