# NASM: Is it possible to access NASM structures from C?

Tags: c, assembly, interop, nasm

Say I have a struct like this in NASM

```
struc MyStruct
    .a resq 1
    .b resq 1
    .c resq 1
endstruc
```

What declaration in C can I use to access MyStruct.a through MyStruct.c?

C doesn't permit dots in symbols. So even If I make the symbol MyStruct.a global I can't use an `extern` directive in C to access it.

The reason I want to do this is because I don't want to convert my NASM structs into C headers. But If there is no other option I will do that in the end to access my structures in C so that I can do stuff like

```
void cfunc(MyStruct* s){
    s->a = 1;
    s->b = 2;
    s->c = 3;
}
```

And then back in NASM

```
mov rax, [rbx + MyStruct.a]
```

Comment: Even if you somehow get the field offsets into C, the compiler will have no idea about the types.

Comment: What happens if you do a `typedef struct` corresponding to the assembler one before declaring the `extern` object? And no you can't name identifiers `.a` in C.

Comment: @Lundin that is what I was afraid off. I will have to write a script to do this then and make C equivalents of my NASM structs. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need to write something converting those structs to the C headers. Remember to use compiler specific packing attributes as C structs may have padding

Comment: Pretty common to have a script running from the IDE and generating C files before compilation, if you need the assembler to stay modifiable.

Comment: Indeed, you might very well have a code generator that generates *both* the C declarations and the corresponding NASM declarations, which might be an easier way to ensure that they remain in sync.

Comment: @Lundin: Or the reverse, define your structs in C and generate asm `equ` definitions with `offsetof`, like shown in [How to access a C struct member in ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77815245) . So your struct definitions are in one place, in C where you can associate types with them, not just sizes.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that instead. Thanks for the input. I'll close the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP requested it closed.

Answer (score 1):

As many have pointed out in the comments. It isn't possible to have C be aware of the exact structures of NASM without an outside program doing the conversion from NASM struc to a C Header file.

I did find out however, that doing something like this:

```
global MyStruct_c
MyStruct_c: dq MyStruct.c
```

Defines memory location with the desired offset stored int there. `equ` also works but the compiler treats it as a pointer anyway so it becomes real confusing.

Closing this question.

Comment: `equ` isn't a pointer, it's an assemble-time constant, similar to a `%define` but evaluated once.  Like `MyStruct_c equ 4` / `add eax, [rdi + MyStruct_c]` would load the second `int` of a struct.  You don't want to have to load struct offsets from `.rodata` into registers like runtime variables, you want to use them as small integers as part of addressing modes like a C compiler would.  To use this, you'd need `mov rcx, MyStruct_c` / `add eax, [rdi + rcx]`, so two instructions instead of one, and a spare reg.

Comment: @PeterCordes  I know, but the compiler treats is as memory locatoin like a variable. It tries to dereference the constant when its defined with `equ` and also declared `global`. unless there is a global type for NASM like `function` or `data` is, the gcc compiler assumes its a variable and thus treat it like a memory location.
You can test this easily by writing an assembly file with
```
    global my_const
    my_const equ MyStruct.c
```
and then in c
```
    extern my_const;
    void func(){
        unsigned int x = my_const;
    }
```

Comment: If you are programming for one particular platform, the structure layout is determined by ABI.  So it's easy to just lay out the corresponding C structures by hand.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about.  `mov eax, foo` is always mov-immediate, whether `foo` is a label, an `equ`, or an extern symbol defined in another file.  This isn't MASM, you only get a memory reference if you use `[]`.

Comment: Do you mean if you write a C program that does `extern uint64_t MyStruct_c` to use this value, instead of using the preprocessor?  Yuck, that's inefficient.  But yes, if you exported an `equ` with `global`, you'd want to declare it in C like `extern const char MyStruct_c[]` and use `(size_t)MyStruct_c` to get the "value".  (You still need a cast since the symbol address is the value you want, and declared as `char MyStruct_c[]`, `MyStruct_c` has type `char*`.)

Comment: Yes thats what I ment. You can also just do `&MyStruct_c` so thats why I said `the compiler considers it a memory address`